# jQuery Content Slider Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-accordion

If you visit...

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/index.html

I am currently designing that website, now click on the button at the bottom that says "Click To Inquire". Why is it that when the content slides, the bottom of the container for the content of the page, does not go 100% as it is supposed to do, as called in the CSS file? I would also like to be able to click again on the button to close the content all together.

You can view the CSS here...

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/style.css

And you can also view the JavaScript/jQuery here...

http://www.noxinnovations.com/portfolio/thecommonwealth/javascript.js

Thank you very much,
Aaron

Comment: 100% wide?  100% tall?  Please describe more about how you want it to work.  The newly revealed content pushes everything down just as expected.

Comment: For your second question, just use jQuery's `slideToggle()`

Comment: @Sparky672 Yes, this is true, but the whole container of the page is supposed be a certain color, and when I open the jQuery Accordian Content Slider, it pushes the logo and everything down as excpted, but add's quite the overhead on the page, below. You can see there is quite a bit of space, that is not supposed to be there. And it stops the container colors from continuing.

Comment: @Spark672 How would I come accross adding the... slideToggle() To the JavaScript? I am new to JavaScript and jQuery and appreciate your assistance very much. :).

Comment: @Aaron:  Quote:  _"add's quite the overhead on the page, below."_ Adds overhead?  What overhead?  Below what?  Space is not supposed to be where?  What container colors?  Everything is black except for the white input elements.

Comment: **Sidenote:**  Sometimes people forget these things (non-compliant code?) look/act differently in different browsers and then assume we're all seeing the same things.

Comment: [Click HERE for more on slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

Comment: @Sparky627 Overhead as in... Once activated the opened Accordian content area seems to push everything down as planned accordingly, but if you scroll down. The logo is supposed to be touching the very bottom of the window. I have the height of the container in which contains the content and according to be 100%. When the accordian is active, the container no longer acts as 100%, it's odd. And I may have a brighter Monitor, but there are two different colors there. Thank you very much again. :)

Comment: @Sparky627 . When I mean overhead it basically stops the repeat of the color and almost nullifies the height: 100% on the container of the content and accordian. Technically, if you could see both the colors, it adds more blank space below the logo at the bottom. Which is odd.

Comment: @Aaron: And you continue to assume I know what you're talking about.  I am on a high quality color-calibrated monitor at 1920 x 1200 pixels using a compliant browser and I only see ONE uniform background color which does not change after opening the div.

Comment: @Aaron:  Using my pixel ruler, you have 58 pixels from the bottom of your logo to the bottom of the window.  After opening the div, you still have 58 pixels from the bottom of your logo to the bottom of the window.  The same is true above the logo before & after with roughly 61 pixels measured both ways.

Comment: @Sparky627 . Reload the page, by doing a cache - refresh, and then you now should be able to see the color issue I am speaking of when applied to height 100%.

Comment: @Aaron:  What exactly is the issue?!  You have red running down through your content... and it's still red both before and after opening the div.  In other words, opening/closing the div makes no difference to your red background.

Comment: @Sparky627 http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/847/errorho.png/ If you view the image you can see there is unecessary space below it... lol That, my friend, is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @Aaron:  Like I said about a dozen comments ago, I'm not seeing that issue in my browser at all.  Run your code through a [compliance checker](http://validator.w3.org) and fix all the little problems you may find.  It might not make any difference but it's the place to start.

Comment: @Sparky672: It only appears to have the error as shown in the image I provided in Google Chrome, not Internet Explorer 9 or Mozilla Firefox. I did the Validation checker and only found a few problems, but they were simple XHTML 1.0 Strict errors, that had no relevance to the Accordian Content Slider. Thank you very much though.

Comment: @Aaron:  That is very odd... Chrome is based on Webkit.  I'm using Safari which is also based on Webkit and I never saw your issue.  Again, you may think your validation issues are irrelevant but you cannot expect a browser to render code within compliance standards when your code does not follow compliance standards.

Comment: @Sparky672 That is very odd, now that you have specified the fact that it works in Safari but not fully in Google Chrome. Hmm, very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION to

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION    
$('div.inquirebutton').click(function() {
    $('div.inquirecontent').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my problem with the collapsing issue lol. Thanks again.

Comment: @Aaron:  Very curious why you'd accept an answer that doesn't even address your main question.  I suggested using slideToggle up in comments first but did not think to submit it as an answer because it's **incomplete**... I still don't know what the root of the main question is all about.  Good luck!

Comment: @Spark672: I accepted the answer because no one except for you and Kei are paying any attention to my question. And like I said, it fixed one of the issues, but seeing as no one else is providing the answer the other problem, which through trial and error now only occurs in Google Chrome, most as well give up on community support. I have already seamlessly got -2 Reputation for asking a question, that I feel is relative to learning in a sense.

Comment: @Aaron:  In all fairness to this awesome community, a well-written question with lots of description will get lots of good answers.  I may seem harsh but I was only trying to get you to improve the wording of your question so we could understand what you really wanted.  You used a lot of misleading terminology where you could have more easily & directly described _"extra padding below the logo when the div was expanded"_.  And you should understand that I **never** saw your issue occur in my browser which is why the wording of your complaint seemed very vague to me.

Comment: @Sparky672: I agree that this an awesome community, but have not got any more responses besides yours and Kei's. I recreated the question with as much as information as possible. Thank you very much for your assistance.